# C++: Rounding up long to suit 64kb

Tags: c++, windows, math

I would like to read data in 64kb chunks.
Often, the data that actually need is not exactely this size, for example 2760 bytes.
I am not sure if there is a simple calculation that I can use to read 64kb or a mulitple of it.
I hope I could explain it well.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You have 2860 bytes and want to read a multiple of 64kB? How?

Comment: I will read more bytes if necessary and just strip them later.

Comment: So just read the nearest multiple of 64k then...

Comment: And how is that calculated?

Comment: Like `(n + 65535) / 65536`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the rounding you can use the formula

```
int rounded_size = (size + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE;
```

if block size is also a power of two this can be simplified to

```
int rounded_size = (size + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) & ~(BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
```

To find the number of blocks instead you can use

```
int blocks = (size + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
```

or

```
int blocks = (size + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) >> BLOCK_BITS;
```

Comment: One day I'm going to write my own, magic compiler that is clever enough to recognize powers of two and use bitwise instructions when possible, so that poor users don't have to do all this mental work themselves.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No need to wait. For example gcc is already smart enough to convert `(x + 255) / 256 * 256` into adding 255 and then clearing low-order bits.